# Show keyboard on mobile only on long press or focus? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to display my keyboard on mobile phones only on long press or focus input?

Currently, every time I click on the input field from my mobile phone, my keyboard pops up. This is the default behaviour of mobile browsers but I don't want that. I want them to show me only on focus or on the long press keyboard.

This is my input:

```html
<input
  type="number"
  onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48"
  oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
  maxlength="4"
  minlength="1"
  min="0"
  [(ngModel)]="set.pause"
  name="pause"
  class="form-control radius"
/>
```

I use angular 9 so the solution in the case of jQuery would not mean much to me.
Is it even possible to do what I want?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode ?

Comment: You can use the onkeypress event and then assign it to a js function which focuses the input feild.

Comment: @coder9927 friend, i really appreciate your help but can you help me with code help or any links tutorial? I if I knew how I wouldn't ask.

Comment: @callback i'm not sure these attributes can help me.